# Unity OnWillCreateAsset ask for DeveloperName

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

when creating a new script in unity I have a script that changes various pieces of information generating the copyright information attached to the file, however while most information is either static or procedurally determined the name of the active programmer can't be determined in either way, I am trying to show a popup before the asset is actually created asking for the name of the developer but my current method provides only an error, is there a way around this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

/*   Project Name : Project Venom
 *    Script Name : ScriptKeywordProcessor
 *    Script Path : /Editor/ScriptKeywordProcessor.cs
 *  Script Author : FaalFaazDov || Raistlin M. Thoreson
 *     Created On : 08/29/2016 12:46
 *    Modified On : 09/28/2016 18:25
 *        Version : 1.1.0
 */

 /*************************************************************************
 *
 * Biophase Entertainment
 * __________________
 *
 *  [2016] Biophase Entertainment
 *  All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * NOTICE:  All information contained herein is, and remains
 * the property of Biophase Entertainment and its suppliers,
 * if any.  The intellectual and technical concepts contained
 * herein are proprietary to Biophase Entertainment
 * and its suppliers and may be covered by Canadian and Foreign Patents,
 * patents in process, and are protected by trade secret or copyright law.
 * Dissemination of this information, reproduction of this material or attempting
 * to read the content of these files is strictly forbidden unless prior written
 * permission is obtained from Biophase Entertainment.
 *
 */

internal sealed class ScriptKeywordProcessor : UnityEditor.AssetModificationProcessor {

 public string DeveloperName = "";

 public static void OnWillCreateAsset(string path) {

        EditorWindow window = EditorWindow.CreateInstance<ScriptKeywordProcessor> ();
        window.Show ();

 }

 void OnGUI() {

        GUILayout.Label ("Developer Name", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        DeveloperName = GUILayout.TextField (DeveloperName, 100);

 }

}
```

the error I am recieving is

> Assets/Editor/ScriptKeywordProcessor.cs(39,38): error CS0309: The type
>   `ScriptKeywordProcessor` must be convertible to
>   `UnityEngine.ScriptableObject` in order to use it as parameter `T` in
>   the generic type or method
>   `UnityEngine.ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, the `ScriptKeywordProcessor` is not an [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) which is inherited from `ScriptableObject`.

You need to define another class inherited from `EditorWindow` to do GUI works. Then open your window in the `OnWillCreateAsset` method of `ScriptKeywordProcessor`.